# Configure nuxt.js application to work in a subdirectory on a webserver

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to deploy a static nuxt.js application (built with `nuxt generate`) to a subdirectory of a webserver. nuxt places the generated files in the `dist` directory by default:

[image: default output]

If I start a webserver on the *parent directory* of the `dist` folder and open the page with:

`http://localhost:34360/dist/`

the site fails to load the script files from the domain root directory:

[image: 404 Default]

I've tried setting the `publicPath` property in the nuxt config:

```
build: {
  publicPath: '/dist/'
}
```

The appplication compiles to:

[image: output with publicPath]

Now, nuxt moves the script files one level lower (/dist/dist) and searches on root level again (/dist), thus still not finding the files

[image: error with publicpath]

**How can I configure the site, such that scripts and assets are loaded and it is self contained, no matter on which directory on my server I put it?**

The issue has been covered [on GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2021) but the suggested hints (using publicPath) didn't work, as shown above.

Sidenote: I do not want to specify the publicPath absolut (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/dist`), which would work but creates new problems.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need [router/base](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base)

```
router: {
  base: '/dist/'
}
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for! Thank you! And is there a way to configure this generically, i.e. in a the app could be moved to /xyz/ without requiring changing the config and rebuilding?

Comment: without rebuilding i dont think so. maybe only via some 3rd party module. As for dynamically you could do it in nuxt.config build.extend

Comment: Thank you, I will fo with your solution for now!

Comment: for future needs, here is the documentation about router base configuration https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router

Answer (score 7):

To complete @Aldarund answer, I use :

```js
export default {
[…] // some code
  router: {
    base:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.BASE_URL : "/<subfolder>/"
  } // where <subfolder> is the subfolder!
};
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Ty.

Answer (score 3):

In **Nuxt 3.0** use config's [`app.baseURL`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#baseurl) or `NUXT_APP_BASE_URL` environment variable.