# Routing in Serverless nuxt app not working

Tags: aws-lambda, nuxt.js, serverless-framework

So I'm getting a routing problem whenever I use nuxt ssr with serverless. When I use either deploy to AWS lambda or use `serverless-offline` it generates the url prefixed with `/{stage}`, but nuxt can't seem to handle this and either throws 403, 404 or 500 errors because the routes to static files aren't prefixed with `/{stage}`.

I have tried adding `{stage}` to the public path on build, the results in a 404 because now the static file path needs to prefixed with another `/{stage}`. If I go directly to `{stage}/{stage}/_nuxt/{file}` it works.

```
build: {
    publicPath: '/{stage}/_nuxt'
}
```

So looking around I found that I can update the router base to the below

```
router: {
   base: '/{stage}'
}
```

but now the file only loads if its `{stage}/{stage}/{stage}/_nuxt/{file}` and removing the publicPath code above doesn't make it work either.

And this is for the static files, when it comes to the actual routes the homepage set at '/' either works but any other pages don't because the `nuxt-link`s to them aren't prefixed with `/{stage}` or if I add the prefix to the base I get a `Cannot GET /` error when I visit `/{stage}`.

I have tried many different ways of doing this such as using [express](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6270#issuecomment-523638458) however I have had no luck and any tutorials that I found online are at least 2 years old and the github repos have the same problem. The closest thing I have found on stackoverflow that is somewhat similar to what I have is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943966/configure-nuxt-js-application-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-on-a-webserver) but this is for a static site.

Anybody have any ideas? Below is the code for the `serverless.yaml`, `handler.js`, `nuxt.js`, `nuxt.config.js`.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/epndavis/nuxt-ssr-lambda)

serverless.yaml

```
service: nuxt-ssr-lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${env:STAGE}
  region: eu-west-1
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  environment: 
    NODE_ENV: ${env:STAGE}
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true

functions:
  nuxt:
    handler: handler.nuxt
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}

plugins: 
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
```

handler.js

```
const sls = require('serverless-http')
const binaryMimeTypes = require('./binaryMimeTypes')
const nuxt = require('./nuxt')

module.exports.nuxt = sls(nuxt, {
    binary: binaryMimeTypes
})
```

nuxt.js

```
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')

const config = require('./nuxt.config.js')

const nuxt = new Nuxt({ ...config, dev: false })

module.exports = (req, res) =>
    nuxt.ready().then(() => nuxt.server.app(req, res))
```

nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  telemetry: false,

  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  css: [
  ],

  plugins: [
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  modules: [
  ],

  router: {
    base: '/prod'
  },

  build: {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing it as

```
    <p>Path: {{ $route.path }}</p>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to Mountains</NuxtLink>
```

if `Yes` then it should work else try going with `redirect('/{stage}/_nuxt')`

for an `if` statement put this inside else , I think it should work.

Comment: I'm letting nuxt generate the routes for me, so it adds the stage automatically. The problem is then when I visit it in AWS the path to access it is then {stage}/{stage}/_nuxt

Comment: I think in that case you need to parse the right path with a flag or a condition.