# Nuxt.js dynamic subdirectories - the router property at nuxt.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to define in Nuxt dynamic router properties? Let's assume that my domain is test.domain.com (where everything is fine) and then i might have multiple IDs like test.domain.com/87833/ or test.domain.com/87834/ or test.domain.com/87835/

```
router: {
    base: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.BASE_URL : "/87833/"
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you gave a read to [this page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-routes) of the documentation? Here, you're trying to have a dynamic route at the root of your Nuxt project.

Comment: That's for pages etc but I mean the whole project (with all pages and components) to served from sub-directories [the router](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#the-router-property)

Comment: This is not what you're saying in your `test.domain.com/87833/` example so. Otherwise, if your example is correct, my link is fitting too here.

Comment: Well no, the above code example describes exactly what I'm looking for :) Like this question (subdirectory on server) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943966/configure-nuxt-js-application-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-on-a-webserver