# How to setup Nginx Proxy for Nuxt Application?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I have Nuxt Application running on port `3001`. I want to proxy it from Nginx. I can properly access the application directly on port `3001` but I want to proxy it so I am using Nginx for that and Here are the configuration for Nginx...

> nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  19000;
}

http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localdomain.local;

        location /admin {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3001/;

            proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # This is Another React Application of mine
        # Which is working just fine
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5173/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I access `localdomain.local/admin`, I get the `index.html` file served from Nuxt Server. but in that file, there are links to other files (runtime.js, common.js, etc...) for which I am getting 404 error. How to solve this ?

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you serve the application under `/admin` but the js files should be served outside that subdirectory. You maybe need to tell nuxt that it is running in that `/admin` subdirectory so it generates the correct paths to linked files. I guess that might be the problem. One solution is describe in the following post: [Configure nuxt.js application to work in a subdirectory on a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943966/configure-nuxt-js-application-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-on-a-webserver)

---

For testing purpose you could try to proxy the root `/` to your nuxt application. If that is working, it should be the problem explained above.

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localdomain.local;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3001/;

            proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        # This is Another React Application of mine
        # Which is working just fine
        #location / {
        #    proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5173/;
        #    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #}
    }
```